# Why can I still access blocked sites in /etc/hosts?

Tags: macos, launchd, hosts

I've been trying to setup launchd to block several websites on OS X 10.11.6

The `/etc/hosts` list is changed on schedule but a browser can still access the blocked sites.

Another strange behavior is that launchd seems to execute the commands when I load the plist, but does not execute the commands during the scheduled time.

Some googling suggested that I might need to reset the DNS cache:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

When I run that from the command line I can still access the sites that should be blocked.  I don't know how to add this to the launchd plist program arguments either if it were to work.

`$ cat /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.hosts.blockingAM.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">  
<plist version="1.0">  
<dict>  
    <key>Label</key>  
    <string>local.hosts.blockingAM</string>  
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>  
    <array>  
        <string>cp</string>  
        <string>/etc/hosts_BLOCKED_sites.txt</string>  
        <string>/etc/hosts</string>  
    </array>  
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>  
    <true/>  
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>  
    <array>  
        <dict>  
            <key>Hour</key>  
            <integer>8</integer>  
            <key>Minute</key>  
            <integer>15</integer>  
            <key>Weekday</key>  
            <integer>1</integer>  
        </dict>  
        <dict>  
            <key>Hour</key>  
            <integer>8</integer>  
            <key>Minute</key>  
            <integer>15</integer>  
            <key>Weekday</key>  
            <integer>2</integer>  
        </dict>  
        <dict>  
            <key>Hour</key>  
            <integer>9</integer>  
            <key>Minute</key>  
            <integer>35</integer>  
            <key>Weekday</key>  
            <integer>3</integer>  
        </dict>  
        <dict>  
            <key>Hour</key>  
            <integer>8</integer>  
            <key>Minute</key>  
            <integer>15</integer>  
            <key>Weekday</key>  
            <integer>4</integer>  
        </dict>  
        <dict>  
            <key>Hour</key>  
            <integer>8</integer>  
            <key>Minute</key>  
            <integer>15</integer>  
            <key>Weekday</key>  
            <integer>5</integer>  
        </dict>  
    </array>  

    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>  
    <string>/tmp/local.hosts.blocking.err</string>                                                           
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>   
    <string>/tmp/local.hosts.blocking.out</string>    
    </dict>  
    </plist>
```

Here are the permissions:
`$ ls -la  /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.hosts.blockingAM.plist`

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel  1474 Sep  8 09:33 /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.hosts.blockingAM.plist
```

I load up the plist with:

```
$ sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.hosts.blockingAM.plist
```

There are no errors recorded:
`$ cat /tmp/local.hosts.blocking.err`

Here is the file containing blocked sites:
`$ cat /etc/hosts_BLOCKED_sites.txt`

```
##  
# Host Database  
#  
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface  
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.  
##  
127.0.0.1   localhost  
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost  
::1             localhost   


# Blocked sites redirected to 0.0.0.0  
0.0.0.0 reddit.com www.reddit.com  
0.0.0.0 facebook.com www.facebook.com
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the browser using a proxy? (Then your hosts file won't matter.) Does the hosts file have world-readable permissions (0644)? Is the hosts file a symbolic link? Does the hosts file contain CRLF, and not just LF line endings? Off topic, but related, `dnsmasq` is awesome for domain banning, even wildcard banning.

Comment: Original settings: -rw-------  1 root  wheel  567 Sep 12 09:05 /etc/hosts

Comment: Changed too: -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  274 Sep 12 12:44 /etc/hosts

Comment: I ran sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder

and I can still access the blocked sites.

Comment: The browser should not be using a proxy, I never set that up.

Comment: Next, maybe it is time to narrow the focus. If the hosts file is used by the system, then `ping www.facebook.com` should try to ping `0.0.0.0`. If true, focus on the application that does not use the hosts file. If false, keep focusing on the system. Is it a particular browser? Some are known for ignoring the hosts file.

Comment: The CRLF (DOS/Windows) line endings can be a problem, too. There are many ways to convert line endings, like `tr`, including `dos2unix` which can be installed with `brew install dos2unix`.

Comment: @Christopher I have the same problem. For me, this issue only affects Safari, not Chrome, so I've been able to confirm I'm correctly modifying the hosts file. Also, it's only affecting facebook domains, not (for example) twitter domains, which are correctly blocked even on Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually checked your `/etc/hosts` to be certain that it's being modified? As a test, I dropped `127.0.0.1 foo.com www.foo.com` into my `/etc/hosts` and tried loading the site; it immediately went to localhost as expected. You might not be doing anything wrong with the `/etc/hosts` code at all; however, there's a good chance the changes you are requesting are never making their way into the file in the first place.

I'd also try `mv` instead of `cp`. `mv` won't change file permissions, it just unlinks the target and renames the source: so you'll need to remember to swap first (e.g. `mv /etc/hosts /etc/hosts_default && mv /etc/hosts_BLOCKED_sites.txt /etc/hosts`, reverse the order when you want to unblock, remember to flush DNS cache after each change, and ensure that `/etc/hosts_BLOCKED_sites.txt` has the same permissions/ownership as `/etc/hosts` before starting)